# MongoDB currentOp() and Cursor.explain() shows different result for the same query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-replica-set

I've been using MongoDB 3.2 for years, and I found that `currentOp()` and `Cursor.explain()` shows different result for the same query.

I found that several queries are being executed very long time(20+ sec), I thought it's not possible because I tested a lot and have index on it. Queries are generally same, as far as I saw. I think they're causing entire database locks because when some queries get slower, almost 40-50 queries are stuck in `currentOp()` .

But when I executed same read operation in shell, it ran very quickly, as I intended. I'd taken the same query from `currentOp` and executed.

When the database locks (I think it's locked), CPU utilization hits 100% for hours, and my application is going to be really slow. I'm monitoring `currentOp` every 1 minute and when it doesn't end for seconds, I had to restart the application then it goes normal.

Here's the one of query that takes very long time. Once it happens, 40-50 other but similar queries are also getting stuck in `currentOp`.

```
{
    "desc"              : "conn32882",
    "threadId"          : "140677207643904",
    "connectionId"      : 32882,
    "client"            : "client",
    "active"            : true,
    "opid"              : 1374027609,
    "secs_running"      : 20,
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(20560351),
    "op"                : "query",
    "ns"                : "db.collection",
    "query"             : {
        "find"         : "collection",
        "filter"       : {
            "p"    : {
                "$gt" : 0
            },
            "type" : "canvas",
            "id"   : {
                "$in" : [
                    576391,
                    570391,
                    767422
                ]
            }
        },
        "sort"         : {
            "_id" : -1
        },
        "projection"   : {
        
        },
        "limit"        : 5000,
        "returnKey"    : false,
        "showRecordId" : false
    },
    "numYields"         : 2761,
    "locks"             : {
        "Global"     : "r",
        "Database"   : "r",
        "Collection" : "r"
    },
    "waitingForLock"    : false,
    "lockStats"         : {
        "Global"     : {
            "acquireCount"        : {
                "r" : NumberLong(5524)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount"    : {
                "r" : NumberLong(349)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(6613952)
            }
        },
        "Database"   : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2762)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2762)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an output of same query in shell with `executionStats` option.

Command :

```js
db.canvasdatas.find({
        "p"   : {
            "$gt": 0
        },
        "type": "canvas",
        "id"  : {
            "$in": [
                576391,
                570391,
                767422
            ]
        }
    }, {}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(5000).explain('executionStats');
```

Output :

```
{
    "queryPlanner"   : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace"      : "db.collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery"    : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "type" : {
                        "$eq" : "canvas"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "p" : {
                        "$gt" : 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            570391,
                            576391,
                            767422
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan"    : {
            "stage"       : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 5000,
            "inputStage"  : {
                "stage"      : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage"      : "FETCH",
                    "filter"     : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "type" : {
                                    "$eq" : "canvas"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "p" : {
                                    "$gt" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage"        : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern"   : {
                            "id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName"    : "id_1",
                        "isMultiKey"   : false,
                        "isUnique"     : false,
                        "isSparse"     : false,
                        "isPartial"    : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction"    : "forward",
                        "indexBounds"  : {
                            "id" : [
                                "[570391.0, 570391.0]",
                                "[576391.0, 576391.0]",
                                "[767422.0, 767422.0]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans"  : [
            {
                "stage"       : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : -1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 5000,
                "inputStage"  : {
                    "stage"      : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage"      : "FETCH",
                        "filter"     : {
                            "id" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                    570391,
                                    576391,
                                    767422
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage"        : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern"   : {
                                "p"    : 1,
                                "type" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName"    : "p_1_type_1",
                            "isMultiKey"   : false,
                            "isUnique"     : false,
                            "isSparse"     : false,
                            "isPartial"    : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction"    : "forward",
                            "indexBounds"  : {
                                "p"    : [
                                    "(0.0, inf.0]"
                                ],
                                "type" : [
                                    "[\"canvas\", \"canvas\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage"       : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : -1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 5000,
                "inputStage"  : {
                    "stage"      : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage"      : "FETCH",
                        "filter"     : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "type" : {
                                        "$eq" : "canvas"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "id" : {
                                        "$in" : [
                                            570391,
                                            576391,
                                            767422
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage"        : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern"   : {
                                "p" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName"    : "p_1",
                            "isMultiKey"   : false,
                            "isUnique"     : false,
                            "isSparse"     : false,
                            "isPartial"    : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction"    : "forward",
                            "indexBounds"  : {
                                "p" : [
                                    "(0.0, inf.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage"       : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_id" : -1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 5000,
                "inputStage"  : {
                    "stage"      : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage"      : "FETCH",
                        "filter"     : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "p" : {
                                        "$gt" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "id" : {
                                        "$in" : [
                                            570391,
                                            576391,
                                            767422
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage"        : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern"   : {
                                "type" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName"    : "type_1",
                            "isMultiKey"   : false,
                            "isUnique"     : false,
                            "isSparse"     : false,
                            "isPartial"    : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction"    : "forward",
                            "indexBounds"  : {
                                "type" : [
                                    "[\"canvas\", \"canvas\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage"       : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 5000,
                "inputStage"  : {
                    "stage"      : "FETCH",
                    "filter"     : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "type" : {
                                    "$eq" : "canvas"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "p" : {
                                    "$gt" : 0
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "id" : {
                                    "$in" : [
                                        570391,
                                        576391,
                                        767422
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage"        : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern"   : {
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName"    : "_id_",
                        "isMultiKey"   : false,
                        "isUnique"     : true,
                        "isSparse"     : false,
                        "isPartial"    : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction"    : "backward",
                        "indexBounds"  : {
                            "_id" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess"    : true,
        "nReturned"           : 2,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined"   : 5,
        "totalDocsExamined"   : 2,
        "executionStages"     : {
            "stage"                       : "SORT",
            "nReturned"                   : 2,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works"                       : 10,
            "advanced"                    : 2,
            "needTime"                    : 6,
            "needYield"                   : 0,
            "saveState"                   : 0,
            "restoreState"                : 0,
            "isEOF"                       : 1,
            "invalidates"                 : 0,
            "sortPattern"                 : {
                "_id" : -1
            },
            "memUsage"                    : 906,
            "memLimit"                    : 33554432,
            "limitAmount"                 : 5000,
            "inputStage"                  : {
                "stage"                       : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "nReturned"                   : 0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works"                       : 6,
                "advanced"                    : 0,
                "needTime"                    : 3,
                "needYield"                   : 0,
                "saveState"                   : 0,
                "restoreState"                : 0,
                "isEOF"                       : 1,
                "invalidates"                 : 0,
                "inputStage"                  : {
                    "stage"                       : "FETCH",
                    "filter"                      : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "type" : {
                                    "$eq" : "canvas"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "p" : {
                                    "$gt" : 0
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned"                   : 2,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works"                       : 5,
                    "advanced"                    : 2,
                    "needTime"                    : 2,
                    "needYield"                   : 0,
                    "saveState"                   : 0,
                    "restoreState"                : 0,
                    "isEOF"                       : 1,
                    "invalidates"                 : 0,
                    "docsExamined"                : 2,
                    "alreadyHasObj"               : 0,
                    "inputStage"                  : {
                        "stage"                       : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned"                   : 2,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works"                       : 5,
                        "advanced"                    : 2,
                        "needTime"                    : 2,
                        "needYield"                   : 0,
                        "saveState"                   : 0,
                        "restoreState"                : 0,
                        "isEOF"                       : 1,
                        "invalidates"                 : 0,
                        "keyPattern"                  : {
                            "id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName"                   : "id_1",
                        "isMultiKey"                  : false,
                        "isUnique"                    : false,
                        "isSparse"                    : false,
                        "isPartial"                   : false,
                        "indexVersion"                : 1,
                        "direction"                   : "forward",
                        "indexBounds"                 : {
                            "id" : [
                                "[570391.0, 570391.0]",
                                "[576391.0, 576391.0]",
                                "[767422.0, 767422.0]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined"                : 5,
                        "dupsTested"                  : 0,
                        "dupsDropped"                 : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated"             : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo"     : {
        "host"       : "host",
        "port"       : 27017,
        "version"    : "3.2.21",
        "gitVersion" : ""
    },
    "ok"             : 1
}
```

I googled it with this unexpected behavior but I didn't find any solution. So I had to restart server when it hangs..

To help understanding, here's my case :

1. I'm using MongoDB Cloud manager and DB instances are hosted on AWS EC2
2. I'm using ReplicaSet and my read preference is `secondaryPreferred`. So all read operations are going toward the secondary node.
3. MongoDB version is 3.2
4. I created index for every fields used in the query (per field)
5. I executed same query both in Primary Node and Secondary Node (with `slaveOk`)
6. The collection has 20M objects.

It isn't happening every time for the same query. I think that there's something else that take effect on the performance (such as replicating?)

But I don't know how to debug this case. Is there any better idea for this issue or way to debug?

Thanks,

> **Edit** : I still don't get what's the reason but tried to solve it by making any changes. I removed `$gt` and it seems to work. But `$gt` has no problem in my previous execution, and I think it's because there's few user at this moment.
>
> **Edit** : I have MongoDB cloud manager so I could do some metrics change, I think Query targeting is increased while I still don't know. Normally it's about 100 per 1 document, but today it hits over 2K. May be related?

[Query targeting for 2month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1sk7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this explains what you see:

```
"lockStats"         : {
        "Global"     : {
            "acquireCount"        : {
                "r" : NumberLong(5524)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount"    : {
                "r" : NumberLong(349)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(6613952)
            }
        },
```

It appears that the stalled read takes its time trying to acquire the read intent lock. This is expected in older version of MongoDB (pre-4.0) since reading from a secondary would wait while oplog apply operation is in progress. This is done so that the secondary read would not read data in its inconsistent form while oplog is being applied.

This is a longstanding secondary read behaviour dating from the earliest MongoDB versions, and I guess you're seeing this now because your database has reached a point where it's busy enough for this to be an issue.

This situation was improved in MongoDB 4.0 and newer via [SERVER-34192](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34192), allowing secondary reads to proceed while oplog apply is in progress.

Comment: Hi @kevinadi thanks for your great help. Yes my dataase is getting much busier than before because we're inserting more than before. But the amount is not that different. https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqn9u5wj2tu7v6g/Screenshot%202019-10-14%2011.52.37.png?dl=0

Comment: And I also took your answer and read some docs about good read preference, it says MongoDB doesn't recommend to use secondary read preference because it can cause the issue you mentioned above.

But it causes Primary's slow ops, and I'm still debugging it. I'm thinking my query itself is causing issue so I'm modifying it. Will update on the question!